# RS485 Input Hysteresis

Tags: rs485, hysteresis

What is the meaning of Input Hysteresis in the context of a RS485 transceiver?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It means that the threshold between HI and LO is not the same (there isn't a simple threshold that divides the two).

If the threshold is ideally at V/2 for a simple single threshold, then with hysteresis it is actually at V/2-20mV when going from HI to LO and is at V/2+20mV when going from LO to HI.

It means that once the voltage crosses the threshold where the logic level changes, the voltage can go back a bit without having the logic level revert. It means you have to push extra hard in the direction you want to go before the logic level changes. The current logic level has an "inertia" that has to be overcome. This is for noise immunity and to prevent oscillations when slowly crossing or straddling the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the meaning of Input Hysteresis in the context of a RS485
> transceiver?*

When an input waveform passes either the positive or negative "detect" threshold, if that signal then reduced in magnitude by typically 20 mV, it would cause a "glitch" on the data received. The hysteresis threshold prevents false events in the presence of noise and weak data signals: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/resNetworks/comparator.html). The red output signal uses a comparator without hysteresis. The green signal is the output signal when input hysteresis is used.